# jQuery stopped working with PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have written some code with jQuery Session, GET etc. What happens is when you click a Text Link it should come up with "Success"

But when there's no Data it works, but when I put in the data and fix it, the code stops working completely.

```
 $(function() {
    $(".open").click(function() {
        var status = "Open";
        var ticketid = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>";
        var username = "<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_Username']; ?>";
        var dataString = 'status=' + status + 'id=' + ticketid + 'username=' + username;

        if(status==='' || ticketid==='' || username==='' || dataString==='') {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "core/ticketData.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(result){
                     $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                     $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
                });
        }
    return false;
    });
});
```

This is from my View Source

```
     $(function() {
    $(".open").click(function() {
        var status = "Open";
        var dataString = 'status='+status;

        if(status==='') {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "core/ticketData.php?id=772&username=NoMansLand",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(result){
                     $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                     $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
                });
        }
    return false;
    });
});
```

but when the PHP is empty it works completely, but when it's there it stops. I have tried Echo & print.

Any ideas?

**UPDATED**

Ok I have worked on this, The alerts work when you: Click it, Check Variables, Go through else, but when you hit $.ajax({ it wont alert.

```
     <script>
 $(function() {
    $(".open").click(function() {
        var status = "Open";
        var ticketid = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>";
        var username = "<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_Username']; ?>";
        var dataString = 'status=' + status + '&id=' + ticketid + '&username=' + username;

        if(status==='' || ticketid==='' || username==='' || dataString==='') {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        } else {
             dataString = {
               'status' =  status,
               'id' =  ticketid
               'username' =  username
        };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "core/ticketData.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(result){
                     $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                     $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
                });
        }
    return false;
    });
});
```

**UPDATED**

Removed the site, issue has been resolved.

Comment: Check your Content Type sent from server response

Comment: correct dataString variable.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't concatenating correctly, you are missing `&`s in the `data`, and that's why it fails:

```
dataString = 'status=' + status + '&id=' + ticketid + '&username=' + username;
//---------------------------------^-------------------^
```

Comment: I have still gotten the issue, I can get alert data through but I am not able to get it through $.ajax({

Comment: Is your code live anywhere, @user1471191 so that we can test?

Comment: in a site that's behind a user login

Comment: I wanna see the live site not the code, that you have already provided!

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you declare

```
   if(status==='' || ticketid==='' || username==='' || dataString==='') {
        $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
        $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
    } else {

      // declare it inside the else 
       // this is more optimised
       dataString = {
               'status' =  status,
               'id' =  ticketid
               'username' =  username
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "core/ticketData.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(result){
                 $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                 $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
            }
            });
    }your `dataString`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in the following way with data representation in json format:

```
 $(function() {
    $(".open").click(function() {
        var status = "Open";
        var ticketid = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>";
        var username = "<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_Username']; ?>";

        if(status==='' || ticketid==='' || username==='' || dataString==='') {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "core/ticketData.php",
                data: {'status': status, 'id':ticketid, 'username':username},
                success: function(result){
                     $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                     $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
                });
        }
    return false;
    });
});
```